# Rubyでビットの修正を行う方法

Tags: ruby

Rubyで指定したビットの修正を行う方法を探しています。
公式リファレンスによるとRuby2.7以降には、`Integer#[]` という非常に便利なメソッドがあり、

```rb
i[nth, len] # (n >> i) & ((1 << len) - 1) と同じ 
i[range]
```

とすると、ビットを取り出すことができるそうです。

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Integer/i/=5b=5d.html

一方で

> self[nth]=bit (つまりビットの修正) がないのは、Numeric 関連クラスが immutable であるためです。

という記載もあり、ビットを修正することができません。（Integerは変更できないので、新たにIntegerオブジェクトを作成しなければなりません）ここに記載されているビットの修正

```rb
self[nth, len] = n
```

に相当する操作はRubyでどう書けばよいでしょうか？

ウィキペディアの[マスク（情報工学）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF_(%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E5%B7%A5%E5%AD%A6))の記事を参考に、次のように書いてみました。

```rb
class Integer
  def []=(start, width, value)
    if value.bit_length > width
      # FIXME: valueが負の場合は少しエラーがおかしい…
      raise "Value #{value} is larger than #{(1 << width) - 1}"
    end

    all = ((1 << self.bit_length) - 1)
    mask = all ^ (((1 << width) - 1) << start)
    masked_value = self & mask
    new_value = masked_value | (value << start)
    p new_value
  end
end
```

私が思いついたやり方はこれですが、ほかにもっと良い方法があるかも知れません。ご存知の方は教えてください。また上記の実装方法の不備みたいなものがありましたら指摘して頂けると助かります。よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 背景としては、これに使おうと考えています https://github.com/kojix2/ffi-bitfield

Comment: 後半は省略して `new_value = (((1 << width) - 1 << start) & self ^ self) | value << start`  でどうでしょう。

Comment: immutable なので `p new_value` としているのだと思いますが、`[]=` メソッドでは `new_value` を呼び出し元に戻せないのでメソッド名を変更した方が良いかと思います。

Comment: 例えば `v = 100` として `v[10,1] = 1` とすると `1124` が表示されます。bit left shift をしているのでビット長が増大するのですが、この挙動は想定内なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

とあるslackによると

```rb
class Integer
  def bitset(start, width, value)
    mask = ~(~0 << width)
    (self & ~(mask << start)) | ((value & mask) << start)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[]= が bf_set() で Array でも指定できます 0.bf_set(3,5,[1,0,1,1,0])   #=> 176
それだけだと寂しいので、適当に書き足しました。
高速なアルゴリズムより単純でコンパクトさを重視して実装しました。(つまり手抜き)

```rb
# bf_???  Bit Field ...
# Ruby 互換性メモ
#   一行メソッド定義は Ruby 3.0.0 以降
#   Integer#bit_length は Runy 2.1.0 以降
class Integer
  def bf_set( start, width, value ) # bf_set(start, width, value) -> Integer; bf_set(start, width, [array]) -> Integer
    if value.is_a?( Array )
#     raise if width > value.size   # width と value.size は一致を期待しない (下位bitを優先)
      value = value.inject(0){|r,w| r << 1 | ( (w == 0 || w == ?0 || w == false || w == nil)? 0 : 1 ) }
    end
    mask = (1 << width) - 1 << start
    (mask & self ^ self) | (mask & value << start)
  end
  def bf_and( start, width, value )
    mask = (1 << width) - 1 << start
    (mask & self ^ self) | (mask & value << start) & self
  end
  def bf_add( start, width, value )
    mask = (1 << width) - 1 << start
    (mask & self ^ self) | mask & ( self + (value << start) )
  end
  def bf_inc( start, width ) = self.bf_add( start, width, 1 )
  def bf_dec( start, width ) = self.bf_add( start, width, -1 )
  def bf_get( start, width ) = (1 << width) - 1 & self >> start # self[ start, width ]
  def bf_or(  start, width, value ) = (((1 << width) - 1) & value) << start | self
  def bf_xor( start, width, value ) = (((1 << width) - 1) & value) << start ^ self
  def bf_clear( start, width ) = ((1 << width) - 1) << start & self ^ self
  def bf_full(  start, width ) = ((1 << width) - 1) << start | self
  def bf_not(   start, width ) = ((1 << width) - 1) << start ^ self
  def bf_rotate( start, width, cnt )
    mask = (1 << width) - 1 << start
    rotate = cnt % width
    wrk = self & mask
    val = self ^ wrk
    val |= mask & (wrk << rotate | wrk >> width - rotate)
  end
  def bf_sign( start, width )  # sign -> -1 | 0 | 1
    case
    when self & 1 << start + width - 1 != 0    then -1
    when self & (1 << width) - 1 << start == 0 then 0
    else 1
    end
  end
  def bf_reverse( start, width = nil )  # bf_reverse(start, width) -> Integer; bf_reverse(Range) -> Integer
    if start.is_a?( Range )     # 12..4 だと start.min, start.max 共に nil だが .first, .last は有効
      width = start.last
      start = start.first
      start, width = width, start  if start > width
      width -= start
    end
    mask = 1 << start
    wrk = ((1 << width) - 1 << start) & self
    val = wrk ^ self
    rv = 0
    width.times{
      rv = rv << 1 | wrk & mask
      wrk >>= 1
    }
    val | rv
  end
  def bf_count( start, width )  # 1の数
    val = ( ((1 << width) - 1 << start) & self ) >> start  # ループ内の処理を軽くする(>> start)
    count = 0
    while val != 0
      val &= val - 1
      count += 1
    end
    count
  end
  def bf_max( start, width )    # 1が連続する最大長さ。0101110110 -> 3, 0101010101 -> 1
    val = ( ((1 << width) - 1 << start) & self ) >> start
    max = 0
    while val != 0
      val &= val >> 1
      max += 1
    end
    max
  end
  def bf_min( start, width )    # 1が連続する最小長さ。01111001110110 -> 2, 0101010101 -> 1
    val = ( ((1 << width) - 1 << start) & self ) >> start
    min = 0
    while val != 0
      min += 1
      w = val & val >> 1
      break if val != w | w << 1
      val = w
    end
    min
  end
  def bf_rbit( start, width )   # 最も下位の1の bit位置 0->0, 1...
    val = ( ((1 << width) - 1 << start) & self ) >> start
    ( val & -val ).bit_length
  end
  def bf_lbit( start, width )   # 最も上位の1の bit位置
    (( ((1 << width) - 1 << start) & self ) >> start).bit_length
  end
  def bf_unpack( width )    # bf_unpack( [width] ) -> [val] # 0x52f50170.bf_unpack([7,4,5, 5,6,5]) #=> [41,7,21,0,11,16]
    raise unless width.is_a?(Array)
    val = []
    wrk = self
    width.reverse.each{|w|
      val.unshift( (1 << w.to_i) - 1 & wrk )
      wrk >>= w.to_i
    }
    val
  end
  def bf_dot?( start, width )   # 1 が一つだけなら真 (2**n)
    val = ( ((1 << width) - 1 << start) & self ) >> start
    (val == 0)? false : val & val - 1 == 0
  end
end

class Array
  def bf_pack( value )  # [width].bt_pack( [value] ) -> Integer # width, value はリトルエンディアン
    raise unless value.is_a?(Array) && self.size == value.size
    val = 0
    start = 0
    self.reverse.each_with_index{|w,i|
      val = val.bf_set( start, w.to_i, value[ value.size-i-1 ] )
      start += w.to_i
    }
    val
  end
end
```